# Excel VBA как скопировать файлы из разных папок в разные папки через excel лист?

Tags: excel, vba

Имеется excel лист, где указаны:
-список файлов 
-полное имя файла ( ххх. pdf)
-расположения файла в диске (C://xxx/xxxx/xxx.pdf)
-расположения папок, куда каждый файл должен быть скопирован (C://zzz/zzzz/zz)

Как можно эти файлы скопировав распределить по указанным в листе папкам?

Answer (score 0):

Копирование:

```
Sub Copy_File()
    Dim sFileName As String, sNewFileName As String

    sFileName = "C:\WWW.xls"    'имя файла для копирования
    sNewFileName = "D:\WWW.xls"    'имя копируемого файла. Директория(в данном случае диск D) должна существовать
    If Dir(sFileName, 16) = "" Then MsgBox "Нет такого файла", vbCritical, "Ошибка": Exit Sub

    FileCopy sFileName, sNewFileName 'копируем файл
End Sub
```

Оригинал - [ссылка](https://www.excel-vba.ru/chto-umeet-excel/kak-sredstvami-vba-pereimenovatperemestitskopirovat-fajl/)

Answer (score 0):

Оператор *FileCopy* поможет:

```
FileCopy полный_путь_к_файлу, путь_вставки_с_именем_файла
```

Всего одна строка, но перед ней... Нужно копировать много файлов да по разным адресам, обойти ошибки, получить имя файла из полного пути...

```
' копирование файлов из списка по указанным папкам'
' строка 1 - "шапка", ст.A - имена файлов, ст. B - путь копирования'
' при отсутствии папки для копирования папка создается'
' Формируется список: файлов, которые не найдены; созданных папок'
' список выводится в столбцы D:F, информация: строка, папка/файл, путь'
Sub CopyFiles()
Dim aPath(), aErr()
Dim sFName As String
Dim lRw As Long
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long
    With ActiveSheet ' или другой лист: With WorkSheets("ссылки")'
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row: If lRw < 2 Then Exit Sub
        aPath = .Range("A1:B" & lRw).Value ' имена и пути в массив'
    End With

    ReDim aErr(1 To lRw * 2, 1 To 3) ' массив для ошибок'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 2 To lRw
        If Dir(aPath(i, 2), vbDirectory) = "" Then ' проверяем наличие папки для копирования'
            k = k + 1: aErr(k, 1) = i
            aErr(k, 2) = "папка": aErr(k, 3) = aPath(i, 2)
            MkDir aPath(i, 2)
        End If

        If Dir(aPath(i, 1), vbDirectory) = "" Then ' файла нет'
            k = k + 1: aErr(k, 1) = i
            aErr(k, 2) = "файл": aErr(k, 3) = aPath(i, 1)
        Else ' файл есть'
            sFName = Mid$(aPath(i, 1), InStrRev(aPath(i, 1), "\")) ' извлекаем \имя_файла'
            n = n + 1: FileCopy aPath(i, 1), aPath(i, 2) & sFName  ' копируем файл'
        End If
    Next i

    If k > 0 Then ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).Resize(k, 3).Value = aErr ' ошибки на лист'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Копировано файлов: " & n & Chr$(10) & "Ошибок: " & k, 64, "OK"
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечание: наличие диска не проверяется. Если диск (например *F*) отсутсствует, получим ошибку. Если такое не исключается, нужно дописать проверку:

```
If Dir(Split(aPath(i, 2), ":")(0), vbDirectory) = "" Then 
...
```